# State the Riemann's condition for the integrability of $f$ with respect to $\alpha$ on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $\alpha$ be two functions on $[a,b]$ with $\alpha$ being increasing on $[a,b]$.State the Riemann's condition for the integrability of $f$ with respect to $\alpha$ on $[a,b]$.

Is the answer simply $\alpha$ being increasing?

Comment: No. $\alpha$ increasing is already given. But is $f$ allowed to be arbitrarily wild?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen There is no more restriction on f. So is the answer would be like given epsilon>0 there exists a partition P then Upper sum minus Lower sum is smaller than epsilon?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Or I think probably it would be the infimum of Upper sum is equal to the supremum of Lower sum

Answer (score 0):

The thing I know of as "Riemann's criterion" is that $f$ (bounded) is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ iff whenever $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a dissection $\mathcal{D}$ of $[a, b]$ with the difference $S(f, \mathcal{D}) - s(f, \mathcal{D})$ of the upper sum and the lower sum of $f$ with respect to that dissection is less than $\epsilon$.

Recall the definition of the upper sum $S(f, \mathcal{D})$ with respect to a dissection $\mathcal{D} := \{a = x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n = b\}$: $$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1}) \sup_{x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]} f(x)$$

Presumably you are to substitute $f(\alpha(x))$ instead.